# SQL Server permutations of 3 values of len(n) with restrictions

Tags: sql, sql-server, permutation

I'm trying to generate a table with only permutations of 3 values ('A','B','C') and range(1,n) with specific restrictions. Thinking about it from a python perspective, the tuples if `n=5` would be (1A,2A,3A,4B,5C),(1A,2A,3,B,4C,5C),...

Restrictions:
The values ('A','B','C') must all be represented at least once in each set, and have to begin with 'A' and end with 'C' (so 1 must = 'A' and 5 must = 'C') but the middle can change, and only progress in alphabetical order. . Therefore if:`n=5`, then the output would be a table like:

```
Col1 Col2   Col3
1      1      A  
1      2      A  
1      3      A  
1      4      B  
1      5      C  
2      1      A  
2      2      A  
2      3      B  
2      4      C  
2      5      C  
3      1      A
3      2      B
3      3      B
3      4      B
3      5      C
4      1      A
4      2      B
4      3      B
4      4      C
4      5      C
5      1      A
5      2      B
5      3      C
5      4      C
5      5      C
```

Where Col1 is referencing the set, Col2 is a numerical value 1 to n, and Col3 is a variable A,B, or C

Comment: This is not an optimal problem for SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an optimal problem for SQL.  But you can do it with a recursive CTE:

```
with vals as (
      select v.*
      from (values ('A'), ('B'), ('C')) v(x)
     ),
     cte as (
      select cast('A' as varchar(max)) as str, 1 as len
      union all
      select (cte.str + vals.x), cte.len + 1
      from cte cross join
           vals
      where cte.len < 5 - 1
     )
select str + 'C'
from cte
where len = 5 - 1;
```

EDIT:

I have this weird suspicion that your use of "ordered permutation" means that you want As followed by Bs followed by Cs, but never any other ordering.  I don't think "ordered permutation" is the right term, but a simple modification of the above query does this:

```
with vals as (
      select v.*
      from (values ('A'), ('B'), ('C')) v(x)
     ),
     cte as (
      select cast('A' as varchar(max)) as str, 1 as len
      union all
      select (cte.str + vals.x), cte.len + 1
      from cte join
           vals
           on vals.x >= right(cte.str, 1)
      where cte.len < 5 - 1
     )
select str + 'C'
from cte
where len = 5 - 1;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler) is an example of it working.

Comment: Why `cross` join if `where` clause is present?

Comment: @UserControl . . . Because the intention is actually a `cross join`.  Usually Cartesian products are not desired, but that is specifically the intention here.

Comment: Sorry, I think I explained the question poorly. I'm not really trying to create lists, but I am having a hard time transitioning from Python to SQL, so I thought of it in a more from a python solution. I'll edit my original question to be more clear.

Comment: @happyhippo83 . . . This appears to answer your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I keep getting an error that "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "str" of recursive query "cte". I can't view the output but it looks like it's producing strings instead of rows similar to the output example in the question. Is that correct?

Comment: @happyhippo83 . . . I actually tested it using Postgres rather than SQL Server.  The problem is something arcane about how SQL Server  handles string types.  It is fixed with a cast.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, that fixed the error, thanks : ) I'm still having the issue that it's producing strings instead of rows. So instead of AAABC as one string, it should be 2 columns of 5 rows with 1 2 3 4 5 and A A A B C as the values going down each column. Like the edits I made to the question above.

Comment: @happyhippo83 yeah this is *really* not a good use of SQL. Why are you "transitioning from Python to SQL", exactly? They're fundamentally different languages for fundamentally different purposes and use-cases.